# How to use the python-flask server generated by swagger-codegen?

Tags: python, swagger-codegen

I have a simple open-api-definition that can used by swagger-codegen to generate a client and server application. While using the client is not a problem, I find no information how to use the server.

So far I can see, that the server is based on connextion. There is also a setup.py from setup-tools.

The readme tells me to use `python -m test_server` to run the sever. This ends in a error message `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'connexion.apps.flask_app'`.

My first goal is to get it to run in some way. But after that, there is another question, how to extend it for you application and how to deal with new api-versions.